# How to edit loading-priority for images JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, image

I have two images like the following:

```
<img src="image1.jpg" class="image" id="image1">
<img src="image2.jpg" class="image" id="image2">
```

How can I change the loading priority of the images, so that image2 loads before image1 does? Is this possible with JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. It will load `image2.jpg` first, and then it load `image1.jpg` without waiting `image2.jpg` completely loaded.

```
<script>
  var img1 = document.getElementById("image1");
  var img2 = document.getElementById("image2");

  img2.setAttribute("src","image2.jpg");
  img1.setAttribute("src","image1.jpg");
</script>
```